# Delphi TcpClient(Sockets) and TcpServer(Sockets) connection?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am trying to connect from a PC to another PC in Delphi using TcpClient(Sockets) and TcpServer(Sockets).

Is it possible to connect like this? And if possible, how do I connect them to each other?

Comment: Probably you can try your hands on this after search about it in web an then post if anywhere you are stuck up

Comment: I did do a search before I came here and I read numerous pages and nothing really helped me with my problem. This site was a link in my search, that's how I got to this site.

Comment: Hope you are looking for something like [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa112602a.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if want to exchange data between these 2 pcs you can use indy components, on source forge you will  [DEMO SAMPLES](http://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/)

Comment: Thanks for the link I looked at it but it sadly uses the indy components which I can't use. But thanks.

Comment: Indy comes with Delphi, you may donwload latest version on INDY 10 from project repository

Comment: Ok but is it a package you have to install ?